# ～と多い here meaning?

Tags: meaning, particle-と

> 姉とほぼ入れ替わりでこの家に住み始めた祖父の持ち物は薬と洋服くらいだが、服の量だけはキャスター付き衣類ケース三つぶん**と多かった**。

How are と + 多い (+ た) used here? What does it mean (what would be the literal translation of the part starting with 服の量...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

・Breakdown (as crude as it is):

> 服の量(*amount of clothes*) + だけ(*only*) + は(topic/subject marker) + キャスター付き衣類ケース三つ(*three wheeled clothes boxes*) + ぶん(*worth*) + と(quotative?) + 多かった(*was a lot/large*)。

・Literal translation:

> ..., only the amount of clothes -- three wheeled clothes boxes' worth -- was large.

「キャスター付き衣類ケース三つぶんと」 is inserted between the subject/topic (plus its marker) 「服の量だけは」 and the predicate 「多かった」 in order to specify exactly how large the amount of his clothes was by "quoting" the actual quantity of them.

Other examples using "quantity/number + と", gleaned from the web:

> 教育程度は中学卒業の割合が68.8％と高かった
>   今回の給料は92,000円程と少なかった
>   在職期間が3ヶ月と短かったのですが...

Answer (score 0):

It was many cases that only quantity of clothes equal to three ~. In simple ,服の量が多かった。