# これなら５分と持たずに… (purpose of と particle)

Tags: particle-と

[image: 伊藤：塔矢は負ける！これなら５分と持たずに]

I understand this sentence as meaning "Touya will lose! At this rate he will not last 5 minutes" but I am puzzled as to why と is used here

[With a direct search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%A8%E6%8C%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%22) i see that "と持たずに" is not only a used phrase, but it seems to always be used with time expressions. However I don't know what sort of と this is, and a phrase like （５分）と持つ doesn't seem to exist. In fact a phrase like 'last 5 minutes' seems to be ５分持つ without any particle, so I am a little lost.

I wondered if I should interpret it as a conditional と, so that the meaning is something like "five minutes like this and he will not last" but I am pretty sure that is not right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Particle-と used with numbers: Are these different?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63297/are-these-different-%e3%81%a8) (see the third usage of my answer) 持つ here means "to endure/survive/last".

Comment: this answers it, thank you. I tried looking for something like this but didn't use the right keywords (should have thought to use 'number' instead of 'time')

Comment: Never mind, the title was not specific enough, and this type of と is typically used with a time length, anyway. Thank you for always providing enough context and research effort.