# Understanding the と in 3巻と？

Tags: particle-と

登場は3巻**と**かなり早く、精霊組の中でも初期メンバーにあたるのですが、一人霊力を封印されずに暗躍していたため、ここで久方ぶりの表紙&サブタイトルと相成りました。

What would be the function or meaning of the bold と?

Comment: Also: [Particle-と used with numbers: Are these different?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63297/5010)