# Understanding 1年とちょっと

Tags: grammar

> 悠真「卒業まであと1年**と**ちょっとって考えると、時の流れは早いものだね」

How should I understand the と in bold? I found a previous question here.

https://hinative.com/ja/questions/14258749

It says 1年ちょっと means "more than one year". Does 1年とちょっと mean the same? And why is there a と? Isn’t ちょっと an adverb?

Comment: I think maybe option 3 in this post is relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/63300/7944

Comment: @user3856370 - It doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any difference between Xちょっと and Xとちょっと where X is some quantity. It means *a little more than X*. E.g. 一年(と)ちょっと = a year + a month or so. 一万円(と)ちょっと =  10000 yen + around 1000 yen.

In dictionaries ちょっと is an adverb, but works as a noun in とちょっと. The [following](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B0%91%E3%81%97-541523) should be relevant:

> 「少し」には、「少しの暇」「少しは理解できる」などのように名詞的な使い方もある。「ちょっと」は、ややくだけた言い方。

Comment: So is this とちょっと literally "... and a bit". e,g, "one and a bit years"?

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, I think so. Simply X + α and α = ちょっと is up to around 10%.